# Recycle unreacted ethene

Tags: chemical-engineering

The question is this:

> You want to make oxirane from ethene and oxygen gas: 
>   $$\ce{2 C2H4 + O2 -> 2 C2H4O}$$
>   The flow into the reactor is constant at $\pu{200kmol/h}$ of $\ce{C2H4}$ and $\pu{90kmol/h}$ of $\ce{O2}$. Only 6% of the ethene reacts in the reactor. 98% of the unreacted ethene flowing out of the reactor is filtrated and recycled (sent back into the reactor). Oxygen and oxirane passes through the filtrator.
>
> Calculate the flow of gas out of the filtrator:
>
> 1. with no recycling, and
> 2. with recycling.

---

There has to be something wrong with the question (or my translation of it, sorry) because given this information the net amount of ethene in this system is just going to increase.

> [image: Original question in Swedish:]

Comment: Why was this demand not closed ? There has been no effort from Hans to try to start solving his problem. Usually when such a situation happens, some moderator closes the discussion, arguing that we are not here to solve the problems. We help those who try to do something and are stopped on a difficulty...

Comment: @Maurice Moderators only close unilaterally very clear cases (this isn't that clear to me), other times it takes 5 users with close/reopen privileges to close a question. I don't know why this time no-one put a flag on it, maybe because the OP only wants to clarify the question itself and whether it is possible to solve it. I agree that it would be much better if the OP includes the calculations which lead to the conclusion that *the ethene in the system is just going to increase*.

Comment: @ Martin. OK ! You are really nice.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to ChemSE! Thank you for posting your question here! I worked out your problem like this:

Flowing into the reactor:

1. 200 kmol $\ce{C2H4}$
2. 90 kmol $\ce{O2}$

Inside the reactor:

1. 12 kmol (6%200) $\ce{C2H4}$ + 6 kmol $\ce{O2}$ -> 12 kmol $\ce{C2H4O}$

Reactor output (answer, part 1):

1. 188 kmol $\ce{C2H4}$ (200 - 12)
2. 84 kmol $\ce{O2}$ (90 - 6)
3. 12 kmol $\ce{C2H4O}$ (from reaction)

If the ethene is *not* recycled, (i.e. part 1) then this is the output and therefore the answer. If the ethene *is* recycled...

Filtrator output (answer, part 2):

1. 3.76 kmol $\ce{C2H4}$ (100% - 98% = 2%, 2%188)(the 2% not captured by filtrator)
2. 84 kmol $\ce{O2}$ (from reactor output; not filtered nor recycled)
3. 12 kmol $\ce{C2H4O}$ (also from reactor output)

The remaining 184.24 kmol of ethene is recycled and becomes part of the 200 kmol pumped into the reactor in the next hour. So, after the first run, only 200 - 184.24 = 15.76 kmol of fresh ethene is pumped into the system every hour, the rest coming from the previous run.

Note: this occurs once *per hour*. Don't forget that.

Comment: But! I have interpreted the question as the flow of fresh ethene is always 200kmol/h. If that is true then this question becomes harder. Or?

Comment: @Hans I am very confused. Are you speaking Australian English or Google Translate? Because it doesn't sound american. (I Don't Understand the Comment)

Comment: Oh... I think I got it.

They probably wouldn't give you a question like that because there wouldn't be a real answer; The answer would always change over time. I think that by saying "The flow into the reactor is constant" They are just telling you that there will always be 200 flowing into the reactor, regardless of recycling status, so that you don't try to calculate what the total output would be if no new ethene was fed in after the original 200 (which would not run forever because some is consumed in the reactor every hour)

Comment: Yea sorry, yes you got me correctly. But the original question really imples that there is constantly a flow of 200kmol/h fresh ethene into the reactor. I will ask my teacher about this. If i can assume what you have said, that the TOTAL ethane into the reactor is 200, then the question becomes much easier.

Im actually a math nerd so i did do some reserach about iterative linear functions. Turns out this system will reach an equilibrium, but when it does, it probably contains so much ethene a realistic reaction vessel couldnt contain it.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's just a badly worded question.

Comment: It was as i thought, it is 200 fresh ethene excluding the recirkulating ethene. I have solved this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understand, there is nothing wrong with the question, if your translation is correct. Let's see the reaction:

$$\ce{2 C2H4 (g) + O2 (g) -> 2 C2H4O (g)}$$

The flow reactor was fed with constant flow rates of $\ce{C2H4}$ at $\pu{200 kmol\:h-1}$ and $\ce{O2}$ at $\pu{90 kmol\:h-1}$. Only $6\%$ of the ethene reacts in the reactor. That means the reaction rate of the reactor is $\pu{12 kmol\:h-1}$ per $\ce{C2H4}$. Therefore, assuming a perfect world, $\pu{6 kmol}$ of $\ce{O2}$ would be consumed in each hour to produce $\pu{12 kmol}$ of $\ce{C2H4O}$ as well (see the chemical equation).

a) Thus, the gas outlet of the reactor would release 98% of unreacted $\ce{C2H4}$ ($0.98 \times \pu{188 kmol}$) and $\ce{O2}$ ($\pu{84 kmol}$), and $\ce{C2H4O}$ ($\pu{12 kmol}$) in each hour as a mixture. The sum ($188 \times 0.98+84+12 \approx \pu{280.2 kmol\:h-1}$) is the rate of gas flow out of filtrator of the flow reactor. Of course, this is assuming filtrator does not filtered off any of these materials (it wasn't clear on the translation). If filtrator separates the product and oxygen from the mixture (*e.g.*, by gas partition by difference in melting points; melting points of oxirane and ethene are ~$\pu{161 K}$ and ~$\pu{104 K}$, respectively, and melting point of oxygen is ~$\pu{54.4 K}$), the outlet rate of $\ce{C2H4}$ out of the filtrator would be $\pu{188 \times 0.98 kmol\:h-1} \approx \pu{184.2 kmol\:h-1}$ (with no recycling of $\ce{C2H4}$). If  the flow of gas out of the filtrator means only the gases pass through the filtrator, that should be only oxygen and oxirane. Thus, the outlet rate of gases out of the filtrator would be $\pu{(84 + 12) kmol\:h-1} = \pu{96 kmol\:h-1}$.

b) I believe, the recycling of $\ce{C2H4}$ means unreacted $\ce{C2H4}$ is adding to original rate of $\pu{200 kmol\:h-1}$. Thus, rate of $\ce{C2H4}$ fed into reactor after first hour is: $\pu{(200+184.2) kmol\:h-1} = \pu{384.2 kmol\:h-1}$. Only 6% of it ($\pu{23.05 kmol\:h-1}$) reacts with $\pu{11.53 kmol\:h-1}$ of oxygen to give $\pu{23.05 kmol\:h-1}$ of oxirane. Therefore, outlet rate is:

$$\left((384.2 - 23.05) + (90 - 11.53) + 23.05\right) \ \pu{kmol \: h-1} = \pu{462.67 kmol \: h-1}$$

This would be the outlet rate without filtration. If you have to consider only 98% of $\ce{C2H4}$, then the rate would be:

$$\left((384.2 - 23.05)\times 0.98 + (90 - 11.53) + 23.05\right) \ \pu{kmol \: h-1} = \pu{455.45 kmol \: h-1}.$$

Comment: But the product is never filtrated; it says so in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let R represent the recycle rate.  Then the ethene rate fed to the reactor is 200 + R.  If 6% of this reacts, there is 188+0.94R kmol/h ethene exiting the reactor.  98% of this is recycled, or (0.98)(188+0.94R).  But this is equal to the recycle rate R.  So we have, $$R=(0.98)(188+0.94R)$$Solving this equation for R gives:  $$R=2338\ kmol/h$$ The oxygen reacting is now (200 + 2338)(0.03)=76.14 kmol/hr.  So the oxygen in the filtrate is now only 14 mol/h; and the oxirane  exiting in the filtrate is 12 + 0.06R = 152 kmol/h.  So the yield of the reactor is greatly increased by employing the recycle stream.  The amount of ethene lost is now only (0.02)(188+0.94R)= 48 kmol/hr